# typescript class with nested arrays - Error creating mock array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to define a mock array of objects in Typescript 2.3.3 (Angular 4), but I'm getting errors.

My main data class is defined in a file called `invoice-config.ts`:

```
import {CustomerVariant} from './customer-variant'                              

export class InvoiceConfig {                                                    
  customerName: string;                                                         
  customerVariants: CustomerVariant[];                                          
}
```

These are the contents of `customer-variant.ts`:

```
export class CustomerVariant {                                                                                                         
  id: string;                                                                  
  templates: string[];                                                 
}
```

Now, I would like to create a mock array of `InvoiceConfig` objects in a file called `mock-invoice-configs.ts`. I've tried with this file:

```
import { InvoiceConfig } from './invoice-config';                               

export const INVOICE_CONFIGS: InvoiceConfig[] = [                               

  {                                                                             
    customerName: "CUSTOMER1",                                                  
    customerVariants = [                                                        
      {                                                                                                     
        id: "A9",                                                       
        templates = [                                                  
          "default"                                                             
        ]                                                                       
      }                                                                         
    ]                                                                           
  },                                                                            

  {                                                                             
    customerName: "CUSTOMER2",                                                        
    customerVariants = [                                                        
      {                                                                                                            
        id: "A3",                                                       
        templates = [                                                  
          "default"                                                             
        ]                                                                       
      }                                                                         
    ]                                                                           
  }
]
```

But it produces errors:

```
ERROR in /home/myuser/client-app/src/app/mock-invoice-configs.ts (7,5): Cannot find name 'customerVariants'.

ERROR in /home/myuser/client-app/src/app/mock-invoice-configs.ts (7,22): '=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a destructuring assignment.

ERROR in /home/myuser/client-app/src/app/mock-invoice-configs.ts (19,5): Cannot find name 'customerVariants'.

ERROR in /home/myuser/client-app/src/app/mock-invoice-configs.ts (19,22): '=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a destructuring assignment.
```

I don't understand why it cannot find 'customerVariants' (is one of the properties of the InvoiceConfig class?).
And how can I define an array of nested objects (customerVariants) without using '=' ?

Comment: use : instead of it? as you would for any other property.. because it's the same as any other property.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `=` with `:`
E.g.

```
export const INVOICE_CONFIGS: InvoiceConfig[] = [ { 
    customerName: "CUSTOMER1", 
    customerVariants: [ { id: "A9", templates: [ "default" ] } ] }
]
```